# How add a build type dynamically from a file in Gradle base on Android Studio?

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to add a build type dynamically by read the property from a file when building. Because there are more than 100 build types, so i don't writing in build.gradle file.

Who can help me ?

builde.gradle file:

```
buildTypes{
    release {
        signingConfig  signingConfigs.myConfig
        runProguard  true
        zipAlign true
        proguardFiles files('proguard.cfg', getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'))
    }

samsung {
        initWith release
        versionNameSuffix "samsung"
        packageNameSuffix ".samsung"
    }

    google {
        initWith release
        versionNameSuffix "google"
        packageNameSuffix ".google"
    }
    ...
}
```

and modify manifest each build:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
def propertyList = variant.productFlavors*.name
propertyList.add(variant.buildType.name)

// read property from file
def variantProperties = new Properties()
propertyList.reverse().each { property ->
    def propFile = "channel.properties"
    try {
        file(propFile).withReader { reader ->
            def tmpProps = new Properties()
            tmpProps.load(reader)
            variantProperties.putAll(tmpProps)
        }
    } catch(e) {
        println "[${variant.name}] Failed to load ${propFile}"
    }
}
println "[${variant.name}] manifest properties: ${variantProperties}"
// default channel value is SinaDown
def defaultValue = "16"
def channel = variant.buildType.name
def value = variantProperties.getProperty("${channel}", defaultValue)
println "[Channel]: ${channel} [Value]: ${value}"

// modify AndroidManifest.xml
variant.processManifest.doLast {
    copy {
        from("${buildDir}/manifests") {
            include "${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
        }
        into("${buildDir}/manifests/$variant.name")

        // get the channel value
        def channelValue = variantProperties.getProperty("${channel}", defaultValue)
        println "[Channel]: ${channel} [Value]: ${channelValue}"

        filter {
            String line ->
                line.replaceAll("<meta-data android:name=\"CHANNEL\" android:value=\".*\"/>",
                        "<meta-data android:name=\"CHANNEL\" android:value=\"${channelValue}\"/>")
        }

        // set the path to the modified Manifest:
        def manifestPath = "${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}/${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
        variant.processResources.manifestFile = file(manifestPath)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's hard to imagine a use case where over 100 build types is the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for help me. I need to build a lot of packages (about 40), each will need to modify the manifest file to build. So I had to write a lot of build types.

Comment: -,- resolve it ? use ant or mvn can do it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I had to do something similar today.
Read values from a yml file to generate flavors.
And since buildTypes and productFlavors are both [NamedDomainObjectContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.html) this should work too.

Look at [Inject Build Variables into the Manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html) then adapt the code to what you need.

My bluid.gradle file is something like:

```
 apply plugin: "pl.softmate.gradle-properties-yaml-plugin"
 def configs = project.ext.properties.configs // configs from the .yml 
 android {
   //...
   configs.each { config ->
    productFlavors.create(config.name, {
      applicationId config.applicationId
      // ...
   })
}
```

And my yml file:

```
---
configs:
  - name: brand1
    applicationId: com.app.brand1
  - name: brand2
    applicationId: com.app.brand2
---
```